# Compare two array lists of obejcts with different ids

Tags: android, kotlin, data-structures

What is the most optimized way to compare two ArrayLists of different object type? Let's say I have an Array Lists of Remedies and Adherences and them being:

**ObjectA**

```
data class ObjectA(val data: List<Objecta> = emptyList()) {

    data class Objecta(
        val _id: String,
        val remedy_id: String,
        val patient_id: String,
        val date_created: Long,
        val is_ongoing: Boolean?,
        val start_date: Long,
        val medicine_id: String,
        val instruction: String,
        val medicine_name: String,
        val medicine_type: String,
        val end_date: Long,
        val repeat_cycle: Int,
        val allow_edit: Boolean,
        //val schedule: List<Schedule>?,
        val is_current: Boolean,
        //val medicine: Medicine?,
        val price: Float
    )
}
```

**ObjectB**

```
data class ObjectB(val data: List<Objectb> = emptyList()) {

    data class Objectb(
        val _id: String,
        val adherence_id: String,
        val patient_id: String,
        val remedy_id: String,
        val alarm_time: String,
        val action: String,
        val action_time: String,
        val dose_discrete: String,
        val dose_quantity: Int,
        val note: String
    )
}
```

How can I compare both those two array lists "remedyList" and "adherencesList" where remedy_id is the same and remove items in adherencesList when remedy_id is not present in remedyList.

Comment: So you have a list of `Remedies` and each `Remedies` contains a list of `Remedy`. Similarly for `Adherences` and what you want is to pair up `Remedy` and `Adherence` with common `remedy_id`. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Is `remedy_id` unique for all `Remedy` and for all `Adherence`? Or it possible that two `Remedy` or two `Adherence` can have same `remedy_id`?

Comment: No, it's unique for all `Remedy` and `Adherence`

Comment: Also, for each `remedy_id`, is it guaranteed that there exists one `Remedy` and one `Adherence`?

Comment: For each `remedy_id` there exists one `Adherence` but there might not be a `remedy_id` in `Remedy`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239788/discussion-between-prophet-tech-and-arpit-shukla).

Comment: In the comment you said, that you want the pairing of `Remedy` and `Adherence` with common `remedy_id` but in the question you asked for a filtered `adherencesList`. Can you clarify once, what was your requirement?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

Prepare the input

```
data class Rdata (val r_id:String)
data class Adata (val a_id:String,val r_id:String)
val rList = (1..10).map {  Rdata("$it")}
val aList = (5..20).map {  Adata("foo", "$it")}
```

Do the filtering:

```
val rIds = rList.map { it.r_id }.toSet()
val resultList = aList.filter { it.r_id in rIds}
```

After this, the `resultList` contains objects with `r_id` 5-10. (that is, 11-20 have been removed)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```kotlin
val allRemedies = remedies.flatMap { it.data }.associateBy { it.remedy_id }
val allAdherences = adherences.flatMap { it.data }.associateBy { it.remedy_id }
val allPairs = allAdherences.mapValues { allRemedies[it.key] to it.value }
```

[Playground example](https://pl.kotl.in/y3BiHwI2Z)

- `remedies` is the `List<Remedies>` and `adherences` is the `List<Adherences>`
- First we flatten the `List<Remedies>` to `List<Remedy>` and associate each `Remedy` to its `remedy_id`. `allRemedies` is `Map<String, Remedy>`.
- Similarly for the adherences, we prepare a `Map<String, Adherence>`
- Then we map each value of `allAdherences` map to a pair of `Remedy?` and `Adherence`. If there is no `Remedy` for that `remedy_id` it will be null.

Answer (score 0):

If all you care about is filtering Adherences that don't have a matching Remedy, you can create a Set of `remedy_id`s from the Remedy List, and use that to efficiently check if they exist and filter on that.

```
val validRemedyIds: Set<String> = remedies.data.mapTo(mutableSetOf(), Remedy::remedy_id)
val filteredAdherences = Adherences(adherences.data.filter { it.remedy_id in validRemedyIds })
```

If you need to match them up later, you should use a map instead of set:

```
val remediesById = remedies.data.associateBy(Remedy::remedy_id)
```

And then there are several ways you can combine to compare. One example:

```
val adherencesToRemedies: List<Pair<Adherence, Remedy>> = 
    adherences.data.mapNotNull { remediesById[it.remedy_id]?.run { it to this } }
```